# jQuery: lazy load with carouFredSel plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading, carousel, caroufredsel

I'm trying to implement a lazy load for images that are inside a carousel created with the [carouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com) jQuery plugin.

Do you have any advice or have you already achieved something similar? It seems that it can't do it by default.

Answer (score 1):

@Stefano- what have you tried so far? (Show some code if you can). It will help us see exactly whats going on.

As a rule of thumb with lazy loading, make sure you put a place holder image as the src in your html like: `src="img/grey.gif"`. This image can be anything - but most folks use a small 1px box b/c its light for the server to transfer. It's also a good idea for binding to put a specific class in your html's `<img>` src, like: `class="lazy"`.

So an example of your html src:

```
<img class="lazy" src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg" width="640" height="480">
```

Then in your jquery function put-

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();  //this is why the binding of a class is helpful
```

Some good references to read are [here](http://speckyboy.com/2012/10/18/how-to-create-lazy-loading-images-for-your-website/) and [here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). Post some code if you have a specific question regarding lazyload() with Fred.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Horizontal scrolling)

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_wide_container.html

```
 $("img").lazyload({
     container: $("#container")
 });
```

-- Lee