# How to preload ajax out of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, preload

I'm trying to do this.

I have a slider with 8 images passing 1 by 1. If I click on Next or Prev buttons, pass 8 new images. (All that images are declarated on my index.php) so:

I need to preload 8 images (from DataBase) **out of screen** (4 left side and 4 right side) and when I click on Next or Prev buttons pass each group.

I need to do this for not load all images (it'll be more than 200).

The code that I have is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#foo1").carouFredSel({
       items    : 8,
       direction : "left",
       width : "100%",
       scroll : {
          items : 1,
          easing : "swing",
          duration : 300
       }                    
    }); 

    $("#foo1_next").click(function() {
        $("#foo1").trigger("next", 4);
    });

    $("#foo1_prev").click(function() {
        $("#foo1").trigger("prev", 4);
    });
});
</script>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: And problem is...? From what you say just send an ajax request for 4 images on click. Maybe I'm missing something? Also... edit your post and put code in there. No1 will ever spend time to understand it the way u put it.

Comment: Could you just edit the question and add the code to it, it'd make it a lot clearer ;), rather than it being in a comment.

Comment: just set the current location to a image which is in the middle of your entire image list. set this option after page load.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529816/jquery-lazy-load-with-caroufredsel-plugin, at least closely related.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! Right now I'll try it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preload the images yet without showing them you can always do

```
function preloadImage(url) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = url;
  return image;
}
```

and later insert the image in the DOM.